# Multiple exceptions in one block

Tags: python, sockets, python-unittest

I have socket.error and socket.timeout in one exception block because it wouldn't allow two exception blocks with socket argument, like so:

```
except socket.error as e:
    print("2")
    server_response.setCode(ServerResponse.CRITICAL)
    server_response.writeCriticalMessage('Customer: ' + user['name'] + ' - Connection error: %s' % (e))

except socket.timeout as e:
    server_response.setCode(ServerResponse.CRITICAL)
    server_response.writeCriticalMessage('Customer: ' + user['name'] + ' - Connection timeout after %s seconds' % arguments.timeout)
```

so I made it like this:

```
except (socket.error, socket.timeout) as e:
    if socket.error:
        server_response.setCode(ServerResponse.CRITICAL)
        server_response.writeCritical('Customer: ' + user['name'] + ' - Connection error: %s' % (e))

    elif socket.timeout:
        server_response.setCode(ServerResponse.CRITICAL)
        server_response.writeCritical('Customer: ' + user['name'] + ' - Connection timeout after %s seconds' % arguments.timeout)
```

but I can't catch socket.timeout message when I stimulate it, it catches only socket.error. What did I do wrong with it? Thx!

Comment: `except (socket.error, socket.timeout)` checks the order in which exception is raised so firstly it will catch `socket.error` and if that exception is not there it will check if the exception is `socket.timeout` .

Comment: Have you tried with Union?

Comment: replace this `(socket.error, socket.timeout)` with `(socket.timeout, socket.error)`

Comment: @assume_irrational_is_rational I just tried but now I got only timeout error message even when I stimulate socket.error with false connection. It seems like I'm spinning in circles

Answer (score 0):

I try this explanation because you have put the tag `python-unittest` in your question.

### Simulate the exceptions by `unittest.mock`

- I have put `socket.timeout` before `socket.error` (see the function `socket_func()` in the code below)
- I have created a test class called `MyTestCase` with 2 test: `test_exception_socket_error` and `test_exception_socket_timeout`; the first test raise the exception `socket.error` and the second raise the exception `socket.timeout`
- If I execute the test script by: `python test_so_exception.py` it prints the strings: `socket.error` and `socket.timeout` and this means that the second function test is able to raise the exception socket.timeout.

### File *test_so_exception.py*

```
import socket

import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

def function():
    try:
        s = socket.socket()

    except socket.timeout as e:
        print("socket.timeout")
        #server_response.setCode(ServerResponse.CRITICAL)
        #server_response.writeCriticalMessage('Customer: ' + user['name'] + ' - Connection timeout after %s seconds' % arguments.timeout)

    except socket.error as e:
        print("socket.error")
        #server_response.setCode(ServerResponse.CRITICAL)
        #server_response.writeCriticalMessage('Customer: ' + user['name'] + ' - Connection error: %s' % (e))

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):

    @patch.object(socket, 'socket')
    def test_exception_socket_error(self, mock_socket):
        mock_socket.side_effect = socket.error
        function()

    @patch.object(socket, 'socket')
    def test_exception_socket_timeout(self, mock_socket):
        mock_socket.side_effect = socket.timeout
        function()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The execution of the previous code by the command line has the followed output:

```
# command line execution
> python test_so_exception.py

socket.error
.socket.timeout
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

Comment: I've tried this way, but second exception (except socket.error as e) is unreachable and therefore omitted. Apparently it has to be in one exception block.

Comment: Have you run the test code by the command line: `python test_so_exception.py`? If you are able to run this code you can see that the first test (`test_exception_socket_error()`) cause the print of string `socket.error` and this means that the socket.error exception is raised. May be I have not understood your real problem. Sorry...

Comment: sorry for late reply. Like I said if I split one exception block where socket.error, socket.timeout are, into two blocks, the latter is unreachable therefore I have to put them into one block if I want both of them to work. The problem was that usually the first error (socket.error) was shown no matter what I do and socket.timeout was omitted. I have decided that I will leave them both because I need to know error messages were. Thank you for your help.